# virt-manager gui default values customization

Tags: virt-manager

Is it possible to configure virt-manager (libvirt) so that when an operator opens the GUI to add a disk, the default value for "Cache mode" is "none"?

Comment: I found some informations here:
https://github.com/OpenNebula/docs/blob/master/source/administration/virtualization/kvmg.rst

Unfortunately it's related to OpenNebula as you can see, and it seems that the parameter DEFAULT_ATTACH_CACHE does not exist in libvirt ...
Still searching for a solution :)

Comment: I think there is no way other than change code in virt-manager:

https://git.fedorahosted.org/cgit/virt-manager.git/commit/?id=fb7868db19a0f9b6e6a09fa6ebd264261a2e5e5f

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my comment before the only way I found was to modify the source code of virt-manager (0.9.5, not the last release).
So after downloading from git, opening uihelpers.py I changed some part of code as follows:

```
def build_cache_combo(vm, combo, no_default=False):
    ignore = vm
    dev_model = gtk.ListStore(str, str)
    combo.set_model(dev_model)
    text = gtk.CellRendererText()
    combo.pack_start(text, True)
    combo.add_attribute(text, 'text', 1)
    dev_model.set_sort_column_id(0, gtk.SORT_ASCENDING)

    combo.set_active(-1)

#    for m in virtinst.VirtualDisk.cache_types:
#        dev_model.append([m, m])

    i_foo=0                     #added
    for m in virtinst.VirtualDisk.cache_types:
    i_foo += 1                  #added
        dev_model.append([m, m])
        if m == "none":         #added
      i_none=i_foo              #added

    if not no_default:
        dev_model.append([None, "default"])
#    combo.set_active(0)
    combo.set_active(i_none)    #added
```

This is the first time I'm working with python, have mercy if you find some conceptual mistake.